# e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type: ErrorScope

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-android-extensions

I get this error after upgrading my room version from 2.2.6 to 2.4.2. and also my target and compile SDK from 30 to 31.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```

do I require a specific a specific kotlin version for this to work

```
 e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error 
 type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class <ERROR CLASS> with arguments: 
org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@767762f7}
[ERROR : HashMap<String, Any?>]
```

Here is the kotlin error

```
 /Users/murainoyakubu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files- 
 2.1/89892cec6b04c2be3667215fa90e8109/jetified-room-ktx-2.4.2- 
  api.jar!/META-INF/room-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was 
  compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary 
 version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be 
   created for error type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class 
   <ERROR CLASS> with arguments: 

  org.jetbrains.kotlin.types
 .IndexedParametersSubstitution@767762f7}
 /Users/murainoyakubu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files- 
 2.1/24c7a8534c64d4050bb6eb0ae3981b83/jetified-kotlin-stdlib- 
 common-1.6.10.jar!/META- 
 INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with 
  an incompatible 
  version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, 
   expected version is 
  1.4.0.

  /Users/murainoyakubu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files- 
  2.1/6970427e81b467d5d05be9001f6dfd06/jetified-kotlin-stdlib- 
    1.6.10.jar!/META- 
  INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an 
   incompatible version 
  of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, 
   expected version is 1.4.0.


 > Task :kaptGenerateStubsDevelopmentDebugKotlin FAILED
 /Users/murainoyakubu/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files- 
 2.1/89892cec6b04c2be3667215fa90e8109/jetified-room-ktx-2.4.2- 
 api.jar!/META-INF/room- 
 ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an 
  incompatible version of 
 Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected 
 version is 1.4.0.
```

Comment: Try upgrading your kotlin-gradle-plugin to the latest version.